# disable perl syntax highlight for only some keywords

Tags: vim

I'm getting TODO and NOTE highlighted when I edit perl files with vim. I'd like to disable the highlighting of only those keywords. However I do not want to edit the system's vim syntax plugin files.

In other words, I want to selectively disable syntax highlighting in my user's ~/.vimrc, after the perl plugin has already been processed.

I attempted a few things to no avail..

[1] :syntax clear perlTodo

.. added to my .vimrc. Result: complains that perlTodo is an unknown highlight group name.

[2] :syntax clear perlTodo

.. run directly from an edit session. Result: doesn't complain about an unknown group name, but the highlighting still occurs.

[3] :syntax clear @perlTodo

.. Result: 'no such cluster' error.

[4] :syntax clear Todo

.. same result as [2]

The relevant definition appears to be as follows:

```
    :syntax
    ...
    perlTodo       xxx contained TODO: NOTE: TBD TBD: NOTE FIXME: XXX FIXME XXX: TODO
    links to Todo
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. The command I should have been using is 'highlight'. For my case, it was..

```
:highlight clear Todo
```

Answer (score 0):

You initial attempts went into the right direction, however, by putting the configuration into your `~/.vimrc`, you've failed to consider the dynamic runtime loading of syntaxes.

At least for me, the following works inside a Perl buffer when typed interactively:

```
:syntax clear perlTodo
```

(If it doesn't for you, install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin to troubleshoot and find the offending syntax group name.)

To make this effective for *every* opened Perl file, this needs to be executed *after* the official Perl syntax script. Vim has the *after directories* for that. So, put above command into a new file `~/.vim/after/syntax/perl.vim`. That should do, and turn off the TODO highlighting for Perl only.

---

```
:highlight clear Todo
```

This one works from your `~/.vimrc`; the syntax parsing will still be effective, but you've turned off the highlighting of the syntax. Note that *not only `perlTodo` links to this, many other syntaxes also do this*. If that is wanted, fine, if not, switch to the approach above.